# Using Tabulate Area 2 update for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, area

I am trying to use the "Tabulate Area 2" tool in the following update:

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/11/26/new-spatial-analyst-supplemental-tools-v1-3/

I have overlapping polygons in which I'd like to calculate the area of lake coverage, hence why the original "Tabulate Area" will not work.

Here is a picture of the output table when I run "Tabulate Area 2":

[image]

The feature zone is working fine, using the ID column I am inputting, but the feature class is using ObjectID and not using any other attribute, see the example below:

[image]

The areas that it is calculating are not in metres, I think they are in decimal degrees.

How can I change the class field the "Tabulate Area 2" tool is using for my feature class? and How can I make this tool calculate area in metres?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 with an ArcView license.

Comment: To make calculations in metres first project both layers. Does class data has any other integer (or text) fields in addition to OBJECTID_12? If not it answers first part of your question

Comment: I used the "Project" tool to change the layers to UTM and now I am getting area values in metres, that issue is now solved. I have added fields to the class in text and integer, but the class field will not select any other fields, it keeps defaulting to ObjectID_12.

Comment: I'd say just forget this add-ins. Go intersect to layers, output to feature in gdb. Export to shapefile and bring dbf file in Excel. Insert pivot table (rows=first input IDs), columns=second input IDs (pick string or integer), totals of shape_area

Comment: Forgot to mention, you'll get much more accurate estimates because spatial analyst tools are working with rasters, i.e. they first convert polygons, this result in sometimes rough approximation of original shape.